# script with multiple calls to plistbuddy fails after first call succeeds

Tags: sh, plist, plistbuddy

I'm trying to write a script to modify the values for a few entries in a plist. The script successfully updates the first entry and then says it can't find any of the entries after that.  Below is the code:

```
plistFile=/Users/Shared/ACADsysMG/scripts/HKCU.plist
CADsys=/Users/Shared/ACADsysMG
ACADprofile='HKEY_CURRENT_USER.SOFTWARE.AUTODESK.AUTOCAD LT.R19·1.PROFILES.<<UNNAMED PROFILE>>'

    /usr/libexec/plistbuddy -c "Set :'$ACADprofile.GENERAL.TEMPLATEPATH' '$CADsys/templates##########'" $plistFile
    /usr/libexec/plistbuddy -c "Set :'$ACADprofile.GENERAL.QNEWTEMPLATE' '$CADsys/templates/MGstandard.dwt'" '$plistFile'
    /usr/libexec/plistbuddy -c "Set :'$ACADprofile.GENERAL.PRINTERSTYLESHEETDIR' '$CADsys/plot styles'" '$plistFile'
    /usr/libexec/plistbuddy -c "Set :'$ACADprofile.EDITOR CONFIGURATION.EMERGENCYFONT' 'XXXXXXXX'" '$plistFile'
```

This is the output.  Notice the first line works but the last three don't. There is no error message for the first line and I've confirmed that the modification was indeed made.  I've checked a million times to make sure the entries are present in the plist

```
Last login: Wed Jun  6 17:39:43 on ttys000
/Users/Shared/ACADsysMG/scripts/Configure.sh ; exit;
RYANNs-MacBook-Pro:~ jamey$ /Users/Shared/ACADsysMG/scripts/Configure.sh ; exit;
Set: Entry, ":HKEY_CURRENT_USER.SOFTWARE.AUTODESK.AUTOCAD LT.R19·1.PROFILES.<<UNNAMED PROFILE>>.GENERAL.QNEWTEMPLATE", Does Not Exist
Set: Entry, ":HKEY_CURRENT_USER.SOFTWARE.AUTODESK.AUTOCAD LT.R19·1.PROFILES.<<UNNAMED PROFILE>>.GENERAL.PRINTERSTYLESHEETDIR", Does Not Exist
Set: Entry, ":HKEY_CURRENT_USER.SOFTWARE.AUTODESK.AUTOCAD LT.R19·1.PROFILES.<<UNNAMED PROFILE>>.EDITOR CONFIGURATION.EMERGENCYFONT", Does Not Exist
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: I just found an article on this site that seems to show that multiple calls to plistbuddy works.  My plist is rather long so I'm wondering if it's an I/O timing issue.  Any help would be apprciated.  I'm going to try mulitiple command is a single call next.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757267/how-to-add-multiple-entries-to-a-plist-dictionary-with-plistbuddy

Comment: Never mind.  I found the problem  The rather obvious difference is the first line doesn't have quotes around $plistFile.